# “Repeated” data displayed in datatable

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datatable

I want to display my `List<string>` in a `datatable`, from another form. The data from the `List<string>` is from `textbox` and `combobox`. However, the data from `textbox` is never repeated but the `combobox` might be similar with previous data displayed. And if this happened, the data displayed in `datatable` will be “repeated” (I’m unsure on how to describe it). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT4bo.png) is the actual outcome. I would like to see my displayed data to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APXNA.png). Below is my code:

**Transavestate** - class that hold my List

```
public static List<string> transnumber_list = new List<string>();
public static List<string> combos_list = new List<string>();
```

**Form1** - form that user input values of textbox and combobox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Save values in the List
 Transavestate.transnumber_list.Add(Textbox1.Text)
 Transavestate.combos_list.Add(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());

 //Go to Form 2
 this.Hide();
 Form2 f2 = new Form2 ();
 f2.Show();
}
```

**Form2** - form to display values of textbox and combobox

```
private DataSet ds;
private DataTable dt;

    //Method to insert data into dtg1
    private void CreateDataSet()
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        dt = new DataTable("Vehicle Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(string));

        foreach (var item in Transavestate.transnumber_list)
        {
            foreach (var items in Transavestate.combos_list)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(item, items);
            }
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
   }

    //To run the method
    private void dataGridView1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDataSet();
    }

    //Go back to Form1
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have two sequences of strings: a sequence of `transNumbers` and a sequence of `comboItems` (in fact they are your transnumber_list and your combos_list, but I don't want to limit myself to the fact that they are Lists, and the names are inconsistent (the first is non-plural, the 2nd is plural?)

Anyway, you say that your sequence of `transNumbers` contains only unique items, but that your `comboItems` might contain duplicates (based on some string equality comparer)

Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> transNumbers = new string[] {"1", "2"};
IEnumerable<string> comboItems = new string[] {"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B"};
```

As a result you want something like:

```
TransNumber ComboItem
    "1"        "A"
    "1"        "B"
    "2"        "A"
    "2"        "B"
```

So you want to combine every `TransNumber`, with every unique `comboItem`.The order seems not to be important.

With LINQ This is fairly easy. We'll use [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) to combine the two sequences and we'll use [Enumerable.Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get rid of your duplicates

```
// SelectMany:
// parameter source: transNumbers
// parameter collectionSelector: comboItems without Duplicates
var transNumberCombiItemCombinations = transNumbers.SelectMany(

    // collectionSelector: comboItems without duplicates
    combiItems.Distinct(),

    // ResultSelector, take a transNumber from the source,
    // and a comboItem from collectionSelector to make a new object
    (transNumber, comboItem => new
    {
        Column1 = transNumber,
        Column2 = comboItem,
    });
```

If you remove all comments, you'll see that it is really a small piece of code.

`Distinct` will remove the duplicates. If you consider "myname" and "MYNAME" to be equal, you'll need to provide an `IEqualityComparer<string>`, for instance `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

`SelectMany`" will do your `foreach inside foreach`.

The `resultSelector` will take one `transNumber` and one `comboItem` as input to create the output you want. In this case, one object that has two properties: `Column1` and `Column2`.

The result is an IEnumerable. All you have to do is enumerate it into a list or something and add the result to your rows collection:

```
dt.Rows.AddRange(transNumberCombiItemCombinations.ToList());
```